# count words in in returning character numbers instead of words

Tags: java, string, file

The program is meant to tell me how many words there are in a file but it's giving me really high numbers. Implying it's reading the number of characters rather than words, or a separate logic error.

```
package wordinspection;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordInspection {
private Scanner reader;
private File file;

public WordInspection(File file) {
    this.file = file;
}

public int wordCount() {
  String words = readFile();
    System.out.println(words);
    words.split("\\s+");
  return words.length();
}

public String readFile() {
    try {
        String str = "";

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(file, "UTf-8");

        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            str += reader.nextLine();
            str += "\n";
        }

        return str;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.out.println("Does nothing");
        return "";

    }

}
```

Comment: I have the file, it's a normal text file.

Answer (score 4):

`words.split("\\s+");` doesn't modify `words`; it just returns a new array. You're ignoring the return value and calling `length()` on the original string. Change it to:

```
return words.split("\\s+").length;
```

Answer (score 2):

`string.split()` returns an array of strings (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-)

```
public int wordCount() {
   String str = readFile();
   System.out.println(str);
   String[] words = str.split("\\s+");
   return words.length;
}
```